# Washing oil off of hands

Tags: cleaning

I made a recipe that was more hands-on and the recipe had a decent amount of oil, so I was wondering what is the most efficient way to get the oil off? I tried wiping my hands before washing them, but there is still a feel of the oil.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid washing your hands with soap?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wipe your hands with a cloth. If there are still traces of oil, wash your hands but  **use dish soap.** 
Otherwise, get gloves while doing hands-on baking next time.

Comment: Trying to avoid using soap, since I've used it before and it doesn't help.

Comment: The right soap will work @Sweet_Cherry, I use dish soap, it's good at getting oil and grease off.

Comment: @GdD I use the normal washing one, but I'll try dish soap.

Comment: @Sweet_Cherry Hand soap is designed to be much less aggressive at removing oils so it is not as drying to skin. Dish soap is designed to seriously remove oil and will certainly work better.

Comment: Liquid hand soap is much better than bar soap for dealing with oils

Answer (score 3):

- Open your tap just slightly on lukewarm
- Rub a decent amount of liquid dish soap on your hands without wetting them first
- Slowly wet your hands while continuing to rub them
- Make a praying hand with fingers crossed while continuing to rub
- Put left hand on top of right hand with all fingers spread and rub in-between fingers
- Reverse hand and repeat
- Rub right thumb in-between left index and thumb
- Same with left thumb and right index and thumb
- Rub wrists too
- Continue rubbing while rinsing
- Dry hands on 100% natural cloth towel (cotton, hemp, silk,  ...)

This is also known as [the surgical scrub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnN6Z-nS6OU)

Comment: The crucial bit is in the second bullet: use dish soap.

Comment: @Stephie All of it is crucial, many people don’t have the first clue how to wash their hands, forgetting that hands have backs and thumbs etc. Personally, I use bar soap and never have an issue getting oil off because I use a thorough scrubbing action.